# Empty application name space in taskbar

Tags: c#, monogame

While working with monogame library I encountered strange issue, where there's is no application name in taskbar when you launch game build outside Visual Studio. Here is how it looks.

**While debuging**

[image: debug]

Title looks as it should while debuging in Visual Studio.

**Launching game outside Visual Studio**

[image: release]

Game title disappears when I launch my game from release folder. Any ideas why is this happening? Can I put a title there by myself?

**Edited**

The problem is not with assembly name.

[image: assembly name]

Comment: You probably just left out the name. I know you can insert one, but I can't remember how at the moment.

Comment: I think that it depends on assembly name, but my assembly name is set to "Pyramid" and it shows original name everywhere except that place.

Comment: Might check under HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\MuiCache for your app name, may have been originally inserted without the name. Related Q/A http://goo.gl/N1cDu3 although it's for the name not showing when pinned to the start menu.

Comment: Yeah, I think that it was related with cache. I cleaned my solution and after changing application name in assembly information it finally appeared on taskbar. Many thanks! If you could post your answer by pressing "post your answer" button, I would mark it as the right one. Of course if you want to get some points. Thanks again! I was starting to think that it is monogame bug.

Comment: I bet Clean/Rebuild is the ticket for all intensive purposes.  Perhaps updating this key is included in that process via VS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that your application listing under `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\MuiCache` didn't get originally inserted with a blank name.

Related SO Q/A [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3158456/application-title-is-missing-when-pinned-to-start-menu), although it's for the name not showing when pinned to the start menu.